# impreza portfolio display/view blank page

Tags: posts

I have a strange problem. My site is in development currently. I have taken over from the previous developer, and I believe this was working for him (I think/hope).

We have a few portfolio pages, but I cannot view/display any of them. If I click on Preview for example, I get a blank page. Browser console shows no errors.

Pages and blog posts work perfectly.

I have enabled debugging, deleted cache, deactivated all plugins - still the same. And there is nothing in the log.

I am at lost of where to look next. Any pointer to what I should control or test will be very useful.

Thanks

Comment: Since `portfolio` is a custom post type, I would suspect that since the old person left, the website may have been updated to WP 5.0+, which includes the new Block Editor. If that's the case and `portfolio` was registered without REST API support, that would cause the blank screen. Look through the theme and plugins to find out where `portfolio` CPT is registered and make sure it has `show_in_rest` set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, yes WP is updated. I thought my theme was updated after WP5. I have now to find out how to check the REST stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works:

1. Uninstalled all plugins
2. ReUpdated Theme
3. Reinstalled plugins

It was obviously some incompatibility issue that only deactivating plugins did not solve.